# POST signout message to Tableau Server fails using Indy or TWebBrowser

Tags: http, delphi, post, indy, tableau-api

In working with the Tableau Server API for beta version 2018.2, the documentation lists a REST api call that signs out / ends a secured session between the custom application and the Tableau Server.

The session is secured by executing a POST request (signin) utilizing a username and password that obtains a token to be used for further requests.

When the session is finished the proper security protocol to follow is to sign out/close the session. This is done much in the same way as the request flow process, by creating a custom authentication header string that includes the token.

When performing signout there is one significant difference, in that the request to 'signout' is a POST request, not a GET request. While this should not pose a problem, it seems to be one.

The main difference between the signout POST request and any other POST request is that the data for the signout request is nil/null. Based on the fact that the API documentation makes no mention of this, but rather gives a simple CURL example:

```
curl "http://MY-SERVER/api/3.0/auth/signout" -X POST -H "X-Tableau-Auth:12ab34cd56ef78ab90cd12ef34ab56cd"
```

...one has to assume that the act of performing a POST request without sending data is perceived to be a normal function.

I have tried this request using the TIdHTTP component, and supplying an empty TStringStream or an empty TStringList for the POST data parameters in the post call:

```
try
  tss := TStringStream.Create('');
  http.Request.RawHeaders.AddValue('X-Tableau-Auth',FToken);
  http.Post('http://<myserver>/api/3.0/auth/signout',tss);
finally
  tss.Free;
end;
```

...but receive an 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized' exception.

If I attempt to do this with a TWebBrowser interface:

```
var
  flags,headers,postdata,targetframe,url: OleVariant;
begin
  url := 'http://<myserver>/api/3.0/auth/signout';
  headers := 'X-Tableau-Auth: ' + FToken + #13#10;
  targetframe := 1;
  flags := 1;
  postdata := VarArrayCreate([0,1],varByte);
  postdata[0] := 1;
  Navigate2(URL,flags,targetframe,postdata,Headers);
end;
```

...the first time I get an undesired launch of Internet Exploder, with the signout url in the url box, and a page displayed that says 'Navigation canceled'.

If I run the code again I get another undesired Internet Exploder launch, this time with the the following response/page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<tsResponse xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableau.com/api http://tableau.com/api/ts-api-3.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tableau.com/api">
-<error code="401002">
<summary>Unauthorized Access</summary>
<detail>Invalid authentication credentials were provided.</detail>
</error>
```

I would much rather use the TIdHttp component for this minor task, but have to use the TWebBrowser for the visual tasks, so I could use that as well.

Here is the link to the Tableau Server documentation for the signout api call:

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Sign_Out%3FTocPath%3DAPI%2520Reference|_____90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. In my code the header with auth info was not being added. Also, set `http.Connection` to 'close'.

That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When `TIdHTTP` is preparing a new HTTP request for sending, the `TIdHTTP.Request.RawHeaders` property is cleared out and re-populated with the actual headers that are to be sent.  Since you are storing your session token in the `RawHeaders`, it gets wiped out and not sent to the server, which is why you get the `401` error.

You need to use the `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders` property instead, which is added to the `RawHeaders` while preparing the request:

```
tss := TStringStream.Create('');
try
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-Tableau-Auth',FToken);
  // or:
  // http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Tableau-Auth'] := FToken;
  http.Post('http://<myserver>/api/3.0/auth/signout', tss);
finally
  tss.Free;
end;
```

FYI, if you want to post empty data, you can pass in a `nil` source pointer instead:

```
http.Post('http://<myserver>/api/3.0/auth/signout', TStream(nil));
```

```
http.Post('http://<myserver>/api/3.0/auth/signout', TStrings(nil));
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. I did what you said, and have the headers to prove it (;-) but it still doesn't work. I'm currently exploring different accept, content type, charset etc. options to see if something else is going on.  
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
X-Tableau-Auth: NEzHHW7PTX2GDQ3Vz5_K-w|2vhHHjwcg1zJjC4u5Z9AnJGHEcwSMKRK
Host: <myserver>
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)           Still getting http 1.1/401 unauthorized error...

Comment: `UTF-8` is not a valid value for the `Content-Encoding` header. And if you are not sending any body data, there is no need to send a `Content-Type` header. But none of that has anything to do with your 401 error. Either your auth token is invalid, or the server is rejecting authentication for some other reason. Contact the server admin for help.

Comment: But... wait... the 'server admin' contacted you for help. Isn't that a 'circular reference'? ;-\

Comment: @DeCoder the OP is not the server admin, just a user trying to interact with the server.

Comment: Remy - To be clear, I am the OP, the server admin, the programmer, the chief cook and bottle washer, etc.

Comment: @DeCoder nothing in your question suggested you were the server admin. In that case, you need to debug the server, look at its logs, etc, see why it is rejecting authentication. We cant do that for you.